# User can't authenticate Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, mamp

User login fails. If the user data is entered there is a redirect but immediately redirect back to login. On the login page there are no errors.

This is the RedirectIfAuthenticated code]. The request is empty and can't pass the if.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/artworks');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Try dumping the request: `dd($request->all());`, to see what is in the request. It fails for a reason.

Comment: I get an empty array

Comment: What does the route to your login look like? And what type of request is it? If clearly fails because no data is present, so there is nothing to authenticate.

Comment: @SeverinDK I use Auth::routes(); and $request is a variable of type Request.

Comment: `RedirectIfAuthenticated` is triggered **only** when a user tries to reach the login page while he is already authenticated. Your problem seems to be related to your Login Logic and not the auth check

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I use the generated LoginController from laravel

Comment: The login works on a colleagues mackbook, but not on mine. We both use mamp.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.